# Why this code works in my localhost and doesn't work online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, path

this code below works fine in my localhost, and when I upload to internet's server, it doesn't works.

please, any direction to I figure out this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('ul.pais li .info').css({cursor:'pointer'}).live('click', function(){
            var pais = $('em', this);
            var html2;
            $('.times').slideUp('normal');
            if(!$('.times', pais.parent().parent())[0]){
                pais.parent().append('<span></span>');
                $.post('http://www.horabola.com/times', {cmd:'listaTimes', id: pais.parent().find('img').attr('alt')}, function(data){
                    if(data){
                        html2 = '<div class="times"><ul>';
                        $.each(data, function(i,v){
                        html2   += '<li>'
                                 + '    <a href="http://www.horabola.com/time/'+v.url+'" title="'+v.nome+'">'
                                 + '        <img src="http://www.horabola.com/imagens/es_'+v.id+'.jpg" title="'+v.nome+'" alt="'+v.nome+'"/>'
                                 + '        <strong>'+v.nome+'</strong>'
                                 + '    </a>'
                                 + '</li>';
                        });
                        html2 += '</ul><br class="clear"/></div>';
                        pais.parent().after(html2).parent().find('.times').slideToggle();
                        $('ul.pais li .info span').remove();
                    } else {
                        html2 = '<div class="times"><span>Nenhum registro encontrado?!?</span></div>';
                        pais.parent().after(html2).parent().find('.times').slideToggle();
                        $('ul.pais li .info span').remove();
                    }
                }, 'json');
            } else {
                if(pais.parent().after(html2).parent().find('.times').css('display') == 'block')
                    pais.parent().after(html2).parent().find('.times').slideUp();
                else
                    pais.parent().after(html2).parent().find('.times').slideToggle();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: www.horabola.com/times and http://www.horabola.com/times/1,Brasil

Comment: I suggest you to review the entire code, is unnecessary complex. Example, it doesn't make sense to call `pais.parent().after(html2).parent().find('.times')` so many times, store it in a var.

Comment: @Sasquiha: go to http://www.horabola.com/times and click on a flag(e.g. Brazil), nothing happens(you'll get an error-message"Nenhum registro encontrado?!?", the post-request returns nothing). What he expects to see is what you'll see on http://www.horabola.com/times/1,Brasil

Comment: I got this web site to fix the code, make it works again, and then, remake it (i know,, dont tell me, but, they offered me a considerable ammount to do this job....

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can tell you why without further information.
The response on the post-requests is always empty(no matter if using AJAX or another method), so you have to check the serverside scripts for the reason.

Comment: I know its a weird question. But what has been made me mad is the fact its works very well in ANY computer with xampp ou lampp (in localhost). I already tested it in the three diferents computers, with windows, linux and macos... but, online, it doesn work ....

Comment: There may be a lot of reasons, for example different server-settings. Your question can't be answerded without any knowledge of the thing you do serverside.